# No sound at HDMI monitor on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, hdmi

I have a Samsung S27C750 monitor and I cannot get the computer sounds to it although I am using an hdmi cable which should transfer the sound along with the image.
The cable is ok because it was tested with another monitor.
Any ideas guys?

PS : I even installed the specific model driver (I have Windows 8.1)
PS2 : The sound icon down at the tray has an 'x' on it at if you hover the mouse there it says 'No speakers or headphones are plugged in'.

Comment: Check your graphics card (the thing with the HDMI socket), many of them do not support audio and will therefore not pass audio over the HDMI connection.

Comment: But the audio was ok with the previous monitor!!! :)

Comment: Is the monitor itself muted? Have you checked through the monitors menu for volume or audio options?

Comment: The monitor volume is at 50%.

Comment: At the Sound --> Playback tab there are some entries and they are all disconnected.They are Bluetooth Hands-free Audio, Bluetooth Audio Renderer, Haut-parleurs / Casque, Casque de communication, 247ELH-1, Nvidia HDMI Output (Port 1)

Comment: Nvidia HDMI output is the one you're after, find a way to reconnect it, or see if it's disabled.

Comment: None of these devices is disabled but they are all disconnected.

Comment: Your current display has no speakers. It has an audio output, however. Is it connected to something? The display might perform jack-sensing.

Comment: I will try tomorrow when I will bring at work an audio cable to see if it is working this way.Are you sure that this monitor does not produce sounds?

Comment: Ok, keep us posted...

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a solution- I have a dual monitor set-up on Win 8.1
I have realtek audio on motherboard, but I have the sound coming through HDMI on monitor.

I have this strange little quirk that when I boot into windows without the second monitor turned on, Win 8.1 seems to remove HDMI as a audio option. Not in control panel- sound or Device manager.

So now I just boot with both monitors on and turn the other one off if not needed. Won't effect audio once booted.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the nVidia HDMI output the default one in the sound panel.

Comment: Set as Default is disabled on all these devices

Answer (score 0):

1) Control Panel > Sound > Properties > Advanced

2) Toggle bit depth and rate quality drop-down to something else, preferably highest quality.

3) Unmute button should work now, so click it.